# If $\sum_ix_i\otimes y_i=0$ and $x_i$ are independent, then prove that $y_i=0$ for all $i$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, kronecker-product

> Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces such that $x_i\in V$ and $y_i\in W$. If $\sum_ix_i\otimes y_i=0$ and $\{x_i\}$ are linearly independent, then prove that  $y_i=0$ for all $i$.

What I know is the fact that, $x_i\otimes y_i=0$ iff $x_i=0$ or $y_i=0$.

**Possible proof**

[image: xxx]

**My Attempt to rephrase the proof**

Let $X,Y$ are normed vectorspaces over the field $\mathbb{F}$ such that $x_i\in X$ and $y_i\in Y$. Let $X^*,Y^*$ are the algebraic dual spaces of the vector spaces $X,Y$ respectively, are defined as the set of all linear maps $f:X\to \mathbb{F}$ and $g:Y\to\mathbb{F}$.

Let's form a bilinear map $h:X\times Y\to\mathbb{F}$ such that $h(x,y)=f(x)g(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

We can define a linear map $h_\otimes:X\otimes Y\to\mathbb{F}$ such that $h_\otimes\sum_{i,j}\Big(c_{ij}(x_i\otimes y_j)\Big)=\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}h(x_i,y_j)$ for all $x_i\in X$ and $y_i\in Y$.

$$
0=\sum_i x_i\otimes y\implies 
0=h_\otimes(0)=h_\otimes(0\otimes 0)=h_\otimes(\sum_i x_i\otimes y)=\sum_i h(x_i,y)\\
=\sum_i f(x_i)g(y_i)=\sum_i f(x_ig(y_i))=f(\sum_i x_ig(y_i))
$$
$$
0=h_\otimes(0)=f(0)g(0)=f(\sum_i x_ig(y_i))
$$
Since $f(\sum_i x_ig(y_i))=0$ for every $f\in X^*$, say $f(x)=||x||$ then $||x||=0\implies x=0$.

We can conclude that $\sum_i x_ig(y_i)=0$

Since $x_i$ is a linearly independent set, this implies $g(y_i)=0$ for each $i$.

$g(y_i)=0$ for all $g\in Y^*$, this implies $y_i=0$ for all $i$

Is it a better explanation for the proof ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129521/discussion-on-question-by-sooraj-s-if-sum-ix-i-otimes-y-i0-and-x-i-are-ind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say,

$$0 = h_{\otimes}(0) = f(\sum\limits_i x_ig(y_i) )$$

where $z := \sum\limits_i x_i g(y_i)$ is an element of $X$.  Now $f$ represented an *arbitrary* element of $X^{\ast}$.  Therefore $z$ is sent to $0$ by every element of $X^{\ast}$.  This implies that $z$ is the zero element of $X$.

Comment: how do we say that $h_\otimes(0)=0$ ?

Comment: $h_{\otimes}$ is a linear map from $X \otimes Y$ to $\mathbb F$.  It always sends the zero element to the zero element.

Comment: $f(z)=0$ for $f\in X^*$. For example $f=||z||$ is also a member of $X^*$, then $f(z)=0\implies z=0$. We can only conclude that $z=0$ is the only possible candidate satisfies this conditon, right ?

Comment: and how do we say that $h_\otimes \sum_i(x\otimes y)=\sum_i h_\otimes(x\otimes y)$ ?

Comment: How do we know that $h_\otimes$ is a linear map ?

Comment: You said yourself that $h_{\otimes}$ is a linear map.  And this is true because of the definition of the tensor product $X \otimes Y$: there is a nice bijection between bilinear maps out of $X \times Y$ and linear maps out of $X \otimes Y$.

Comment: If $z \in X$, then $f(z) = 0$ for every $f \in X^{\ast}$ if and only if $z = 0$.

Comment: I have edited OP to include the definitions for the maps. could you please check if its fine now ?